# How to pass dynamic array list to a Post Request using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I want to send a dynamic arraylist as POST request by using JMeter. For example the request will be like :

```
<ArrayOfEmp>
 <Emp>
  <name>emp1</name>
  <dept>dept1</dept>
 </Emp>
  ...
 <Emp>
  <name>empN</name>
  <dept>deptN</dept>
 </Emp>
</ArrayOfEmp>
```

I have a .csv file with Emp name and department. My script should be able to read the data from .csv file and pass to the request. Also each row of the .csv file will be a Emp object. The no of row will be dynamic.

Can anyone help me write the BeanShell PreProcessor for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: you can write a Java code in BeanShell PreProcessor or BeanShell Sampler to generate XML using dynamic values fetched from CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you don't need to use Beanshell here.

Given your CSV file has the following structure:

```
emp1,dpt1
emp2,dpt2
emp3,dpt3
....
```

and you have the following [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config):

[image: CSV Data Set Config]

You should be able to refer `${empName}` and `${empDpt}` directly in HTTP Request body as follows:

[image: HTTP Request and CSV Variables]

If you add a [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) you'll be able to see request and response details

[image]

For step-by-step configuration details and more tips refer to [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide.

However if you need to generate XML on the fly rather than using template update your question and notify me via comments.